# Spinner selected item show at first time run, after log out and login again it doesn't show selected item

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have a spinner dropdrown and it show the first time I run, but after I logout and login again, then my spinner doesn't show the selected item on UI. But when I click on it, it show dropdrow that has values inside. It just not showing on UI. May I know any suggestion, please?
My code is here.

```
public void setSubConSpinnerAdapter(ArrayList<SubContractor> subCon)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "scopearr for adapter"+ subCon.toString());
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), subCon,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,new String[]{"sub_con_name"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    simpleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spSubcon.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}
```

Here is the code for logout

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.logout:

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginAct.class));
            this.finish();
            return true;
```

Comment: I'm using object arraylist for spinner and get that arraylist data from sharepreference.

Comment: try removing `editor.clear();`

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the selected item **position** in the `SharedPrefernces` along with arraylist data

And while Relaunching the `Activity` set the **position** to the `Spinner`

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Still the same. Inside dropdrown list, there has values. For example, at index 0,  "select one value", at index 1, 2... also has the repective values when I click on it. But any of dropdrown value is not appear on spinner UI. That's problem.